# Which is grammatically correct: I am mindful of the fact .... or I am mindful in the fact?

Tags: grammar

Which is grammatically correct:

> 1. I am mindful of the fact....
> 2. I am mindful in the fact that I am not  competent in some areas of the staff job profile  .....

Comment: Given to Oxford dictionary, the structure **mindful of something** is correct
see: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mindful

Answer (score 1):

The correct grammar is:

> I am mindful *of* the fact...